# Debugging a Web Setup custom action

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

Other forum posts suggest that you put a Debugger.Break call or a MessageBox.Show call into the custom action code, then attach the VS debugger to the process when the interrupt occurs in the Setup execution.  Neither of these has worked for me.  Setup runs to completion without the interrupt.  (Using VS2010).  I'm at a loss.  Thanks for any suggestions.
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the solution to debug in VS 2010
http://www.codeissue.com/issue.php?i=i34dd90c3e9e204